# What is the purpose of chain link near Nazir in Dawnstar sanctuary near torture victim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Behind Nazir there is a chain link that we can operate. What does it do?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Easy to find out, with some Googling.

> It lowers some spikes that blocked a quick end to the Cicero chase
> quest

> It just pulls down a spike wall, that's it. Would be at the top of the
> staircase, across from the alchemy corner.

https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Dawnstar_Sanctuary#Pull_Chain

http://www.gamesas.com/question-about-the-dawnstar-sanctuary-t230766.html

Comment: Search google and with what keywords? So it's no longer useful after the quest?

Comment: @user4951 I wrote "point of chain in Dawnstar sanctuary". You may want to amend the title of the question to Dawnstar rather than Dawnguard. And apparently it's of no use after the quest.

Comment: You know what, even if it's in google and easy to find, I do not see why asking it here and add a bit of link and content to another will hurt at all. If anything it'll add traffic to this site. It's a legitimate question. What? Every question must be difficult? People search for that and find this site. What's bad about that?

Comment: Your questions have recently been very low effort or ramble-ons about the game. While yes, we'll accept legitimate questions, we also tend to be against low effort questions that fish for site score or show no effort on your part to do any sort of research.